# Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django

(I searched this error on StackOverflow and tried the solution ideas, but hey did not work.)

In my Django Project, I tried to add a like button to my article detail page. If users like the article, they click the like button and return the same article page. I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXqRPqDjDgc&t=902s) on Youtube and wrote the same code by changing some values according to my project. But I encountered an error which says Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

I read some solutions on Stackoverflow and tried to delete migrations files (except init.py), and then I wrote `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate.` Unfortunately, it did not work. I want to share my code, so maybe you can give me some solution ideas.

model.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Kullanıcı")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name="Başlık")
    content = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name="Oluşturma Tarihi")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/',views.dashboard, name ="dashboard"),
    path('addarticle/',views.addarticle, name ="addarticle"),
    path('article/<int:id>',views.detail, name ="detail"),
    path('update/<int:id>',views.updateArticle, name ="update"),
    path('delete/<int:id>',views.deleteArticle, name ="delete"),
    path('',views.articles, name ="articles"),
    path('comment/<int:id>',views.addComment, name ="comment"),
    path('like/<int:id>',views.LikeView, name ="like_post"),
]
```

views.py

```
def LikeView(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
    article.likes.add(request.User)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("detail", args=[str(id)]))
```

detail.html (In this html, I show the content of the article and who published it, comments and likes)

```
<form action="{% url 'article:like_post' article.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ article_id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> Like
        </button>
</form>
```

You can see likes table in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBCb1.png) I can like a post in admin page. But obviously thats not appropriate for users.

And thats the [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uBQk.png) I encountered.

Comment: Don't know why you even post `"post_id"` considering your forms action url has the id? Meaning aren't you getting a variable `id` in your view. So you can write `get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)`?

Comment: When I wrote (Article, id=id), I have another error which says "name 'article' is not defined"

Comment: I believe Willem already answered that. What is the use of repeating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is `article.id`, not <s>`article_id`</s>:

```
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ article.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
```

That being said, it does not make much sense to pass it *both* as URL parameter and as POST parameter. You can simply make a form *without* the `post_id`, and use the URL parameter instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def LikeView(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('detail', id)
```

Then the form simply looks like:

```
<form action="{% url 'article:like_post' article.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i> Like
    </button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: One can use the [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST)
> to restrict the view to only be accessible for a POST request.

Comment: @mechaphantom: yes, because you assigned it to `post = ...`, and then uses `article.likes..`, and it is also `request.user` normally, not `request.User`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wrote your code in my views.py file but now, I have an error which says ImportError: cannot import name 'require_http_method' from 'django.views.decorators.http'. You have any ideas?

Comment: @mechaphantom: what verison of Django do you use? In Django-3.1, that is where the decorator is located: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/

Comment: @mechaphantom you are missing an `s` I believe instead of `require_http_method` it should be `require_http_methods`

Comment: Thank you guys, both of you. That's worked. Now I can like articles and I can see that likes in admin panel.